# Limit of $(x\cot(x)-1)/(-(17x^2))$ when $x \to 0$

Tags: limits

I need to find the limit:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\cot(x)-1}{-17x^2}$$

I've been tried L'Hopital and Taylor but it's not going so well..
thank in advance

Comment: I'm sorry I edit the post, there was a mistake in the question ,

Comment: cot(X)= cos(x)/sin(X)

Comment: I'm sure your textbook (or a table) has enough many terms on the Taylor series of the tangent.
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\tan x}{-17x^2\tan x}=?$$ First degree terms cancel out in the numerator. Then take out a common factor $x^3$. Done.

Comment: Check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186061/ out as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\frac{x}{\sin(x)}=\frac{x}{x-\frac{x^3}{6}(1+\epsilon(x))}$$

$$=\frac{1}{1-\frac{x^2}{6}(1+\epsilon(x))}$$

$$=1+\frac{x^2}{6}(1+\epsilon(x))$$

So,

$$x \;cot(x)=\frac{x}{\sin(x)}\cos(x)$$
$$=(1+\frac{x^2}{6})(1-\frac{x^2}{2})+x^2\epsilon(x)$$

$$=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^2}{6}+x^2\epsilon(x)$$

You will find $\boxed{ \frac{1}{51}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE: $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\cot(x)-1}{-17x^2}=\\
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\cot(x)-1}{-17x^2}\times \frac{\tan x}{\tan x}=\\
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\tan x}{-17x^2\tan x}$$ then use...$$x\to 0 \\\tan x \sim x+ \frac {x^3}{3}$$